Equation is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities
Solve[{{0 ==  y e + 1/2 I (w eg - w ge)},
   {0 == - y e + 1/2 I (w  ge - w  eg)},
   {0 == -(1/2 y + I d) ge  + 1/2  I w (e - g)},
   {0 == -(1/2 y -  I d) eg  + 1/2  I w (g - e)}},
  {e, g, ge, eg}];

This code gives error "Equation is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities"
It have a 100% solution, but i want to code it in wolfram
y, w, d - some real positive constants

Remove the { }.  Solve[{0 == y e + 1/2 I (w eg - w ge),    0 == -y e + 1/2 I (w ge - w eg),    0 == -(1/2 y + I d) ge + 1/2 I w (e - g),    0 == -(1/2 y - I d) eg + 1/2 I w (g - e)}, {e, g, ge, eg}]

Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory book written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a fast intro for math students as well as a fast intro for programmers to choose from.

Now it gives another error:
Options expected (instead of {e,g,ge,eg}) beyond position 4 in 
Solve[{0==1/2 I (eg w-ge w)+e y},{0==1/2 I (-eg w+ge w)-e y},{0==1/2 
I (e-g) w+ge (-I d-y/2)},{0==1/2 I (-e+g) w+eg (I 
d-y/2)},{e,g,ge,eg}]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules

First, remove extra curly brackets as it has already been advised by cvgmt. Second, do not use slash as in (I \ d-y/2).

Consider the first 2 equations. The second is simply the negation of the first one. Therefore you actually have only 3 equations for 4 variables. Therefore, we can only get a solution for 3 variables:
Solve[{0 == y e + 1/2 I (w eg - w ge), 
  0 == -y e + 1/2 I (w ge - w eg), 
  0 == -(1/2 y + I d) ge + 1/2 I w (e - g), 
  0 == -(1/2 y - I d) eg + 1/2 I w (g - e)}, {e, g, ge, eg}]


